# How to add description in React Storybook -> showInfo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes, storybook

My React component is a DynamicTable. I added a simple PropTypes to my component but i want to add in each attribute a description too.

Here is my propTypes:

```js
DynamicTable.propTypes = {
    tableCells: PropTypes.shape({
        nameCells: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        labelCells: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    listRows: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

How can i add descriptions into my storybook ?

[PropTypes generated into storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJfmt.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use inline comments and react-docgen together to populate this column.

```
Input.propTypes = {
  ...DefaultProps.Input,
  /** text, which is shown until the text is written */
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  /** size of the input, ordinary by default, could be `md` */
  size: PropTypes.oneOf([undefined, 'md']),
  /** mask for masked input pattern */
  mask: MaskedInput.propTypes.mask,
  /** all the rest params (e.g. onClick) */
  rest: PropTypes.any,
};
```

```
babel-plugin-react-docgen (add to .babelrc "plugins": ["react-docgen"])
```

References:

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/2010
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/2708#issuecomment-454156949